# Where can I play D&D 4E by forum?

Tags: dnd-4e, play-by-post

I would like to play more Dungeons & Dragons 4th edition besides the campaign I run as a DM. But due to time constraints it would be best if I could find an asynchroneous game played by writing, a play-by-forum game for example. Never played that way, so you could consider me as a new player.

I didn't find any 4E games on rpol.net, so I was wondering where I would have the best chance of finding a play-by-forum 4E game as a new player?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because RPG.stackexchange is not a suitable place to find a group to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Places i've seen 4E games include:

- http://www.giantitp.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?3-Play-by-Post-Games

  A very active community; many DMs and other players hang out there. Within a few weeks you'll be able to join a pickup game. Games tend to be on the serious side with a lot of RP; people take their storytelling seriously. I've played and DM'd. The site dice roller works well. Nonintrusive banner ads on each page.
- http://forums.somethingawful.com/forumdisplay.php?forumid=103&posticon=727

  Also extremely active. The trend is more towards gonzo wackiness but there's still a lot of role-playing. Somethingawful tends to be blocked by many corporate firewalls because some of the forums are extremely NSFW. Annoying ads unless you pay a one-time fee.
- http://forum.nogoblinsallowed.com/viewforum.php?f=11

  Haven't played here but has a very nice die roller. The community is small but people are wiling to play in multiple games. The downside is that occasionally everything grinds to a halt.
- http://rpol.net

  Haven't used but heard good things about
- http://forum.rpg.net

  Haven't used but heard good things about

Answer (score 4):

I find the community at RPG Geek very friendly.  You can post your interest in the [general Play-By-Forum board](http://rpggeek.com/forum/379243/rpg/play-by-forum).  Read the first two pinned posts to get an idea on how it works there.

When the game starts, it appears in the [play-by-forum board dedicated to D&D 4e](http://rpggeek.com/forum/393432/dungeons-dragons-4th-edition/play-by-forum).  You can browse this last board to see the games that are currently running.

Answer (score -1):

Also available for 4E and all different sort of pbp games is:
[myth-weavers.com](http://www.myth-weavers.com/forumhome.php)